# Getting the text portion of a node using php Simple XML

Tags: php, simplexml

Given the php code:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<articles>
<article>
This is a link
<link>Title</link>
with some text following it.
</article>
</articles>
EOF;

function traverse($xml) {
    $result = "";
    foreach($xml->children() as $x) {
        if ($x->count()) {
            $result .= traverse($x);
        }
        else {
            $result .= $x;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$parser = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
traverse($parser);
```

I expected the function traverse() to return:

```
This is a link Title with some text following it.
```

However, it returns only:

```
Title
```

Is there a way to get the expected result using simpleXML (obviously for the purpose of consuming the data rather than just returning it as in this simple example)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There might be ways to achieve what you want using only SimpleXML, but in this case, the simplest way to do it is to use [DOM](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). The good news is if you're already using SimpleXML, you don't have to change anything as DOM and SimpleXML are [basically interchangeable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php):

```
// either
$articles = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo dom_import_simplexml($articles)->textContent;

// or
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo $dom->documentElement->textContent;
```

Assuming your task is to iterate over each `<article/>` and get its content, your code will look like

```
$articles = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($articles->article as $article)
{
    $articleText = dom_import_simplexml($article)->textContent;
}
```

Comment: This actually produces the exact result I was expecting - without actually solving the underlying problem of traversing the Xml document.

Comment: You will not be able to "traverse" or iterate over text nodes with SimpleXML. Or at least, it will be contrived/impractical if at all possible. Use SimpleXML wherever it makes stuff easier, then import selected nodes to DOM to access features that aren't part of SimpleXML.

Answer (score 5):

```
node->asXML();// It's the simple solution i think !!
```

Comment: have you tried this with the OP's data? does it actually work?

Answer (score 4):

So, the simple answer to my question was: Simplexml can't process this kind of XML. Use DomDocument instead.

This example shows how to traverse the entire XML. It seems that DomDocument will work with any XML whereas SimpleXML requires the XML to be simple.

```
function attrs($list) {
    $result = "";
    foreach ($list as $attr) {
        $result .= " $attr->name='$attr->value'";
    }
    return $result;
}

function parseTree($xml) {
    $result = "";
    foreach ($xml->childNodes AS $item) {
        if ($item->nodeType == 1) {
            $result .= "<$item->nodeName" . attrs($item->attributes) . ">" . parseTree($item) . "</$item->nodeName>";
        }
        else {
            $result .= $item->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);

print parseTree($xmlDoc->documentElement);
```

You could also load the xml using simpleXML and then convert it to DOM using dom_import_simplexml() as Josh said. This would be useful, if you are using simpleXml to filter nodes for parsing, e.g. using XPath.

However, I don't actually use simpleXML, so for me that would be taking the long way around.

```
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xmlDom = dom_import_simplexml($simpleXml);

print parseTree($xmlDom);
```

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text node of a DOM element with simplexml just by treating it like a string:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $x) {
   $result .= "$x"
```

However, this prints out:

```
This is a link

with some text following it.
TitleTitle
```

..because the text node is treated as one block and there is no way to tell where the child fits in inside the text node.  The child node is also added twice because of the other else {}, but you can just take that out.

Sorry if I didn't help much, but I don't think there's any way to find out where the child node fits in the text node unless the xml is consistent (but then, why not use tags).  If you know what element you want to strip the text out of, `strip_tags()` will work great.

Comment: It always helps knowing that what you're trying to accomplish is just not possible. Unfortunately, I don't own the XML, so it is what it is. Do you know if any of the other parsers in php are better suited for my task?

Comment: I don't know of any existing ones .. perhaps you could write one!

Comment: After having barked up the wrong (parser?) tree for quite some time, it seems that DOM is our friend in need when it comes to dealing with this sort of XML.

Comment: If you're up for writing more code, I found the XMLReader pull parser able to handle a tag soup.  However, there won't be xpath available so that you'll have to carry context information yourself as you parse the soup.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered, but CASTING TO STRING ( i.e. $sString = (string) oSimpleXMLNode->TagName) always worked for me.

Comment: echo (string)$xmlNode;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$parser = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo html_entity_decode(strip_tags($parser->asXML()));
```

That's pretty much equivalent to:

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo dom_import_simplexml($parser)->textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @tandu said, it's not possible, but if you can modify your XML, this will work:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<articles>
    <article>
        This is a link
    </article>
    <link>Title</link>
    <article>
       with some text following it.
    </article>
</articles>
```