# get textcontent including inner node

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I would like to print out `"depth 17 - 1 enclosed by 20m contour "`

Below is xml string loaded from a xml file version 1.0 by `$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");`

```
<object>
  depth 
 <emphasis>
  17 
   <subscript>1</subscript> 
 </emphasis>
  enclosed by 20m contour 
</object>


print_r($Vals->object);
//prints "depth enclosed by 20m contour "


$Vals->object->emphasis.' - '.$Vals->object->emphasis->subscript
//prints "17 - 1"
```

I can print string by replacing the values `"depth"` with `depth $Vals->object->emphasis.' - '.$Vals->object->emphasis->subscript`. Its not the good thing becoz there may also have a 'depth' in string and also width may have at the location of depth.

Till now  i am trying with below code, Saw at [Go to Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132231/getting-the-text-portion-of-a-node-using-php-simple-xml)

```
echo dom_import_simplexml($Vals->object)->textContent;
```

This code could not do the job and also make the system to so slow. No error generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php).

Given this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
```

You can do:

```
print strval($xml->emphasis->subscript); // prints '1'
print strval($xml); //prints 'depth enclosed by 20m contour'
...
```

And so on, you can combine them yourself to the string you want.

Comment: its print just `'depth enclosed by 20m contour'`, Not `depth 17 - 1 enclosed by 20m contour ` as I have described in question.