# Parse XML soup in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a few XML files in a format like this

```
...
<section>
  <header>Headline</header>
  <par>Some text <em>here</em> and more text.</par>
</section>
....
```

At first I used the PHP pull-parser XMLReader which just walked through the file, and I could respond to whatever node type the reader would run across.  This all worked quite well, but the code felt bloated and there was some context information that I needed which required me to drag additional state around.  For example, a `<header>` tag can be a child to a section or subsection tag.

So I switched to SimpleXML because it would represent the XML document as a recursive data structure, and provide me with XPath functionality.  No more state (as I can query the context for, eg header tags) and the code is much more compact.

However...  How do I access the `"Some text "` and `" and more text."` child nodes of the `<par>` tag?  Is that possible, or can I not parse a soup with SimpleXML?  Should I better use a DOMDocument implementation, and if so, which one?  Where's the difference to SimpleXML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132231/getting-the-text-portion-of-a-node-using-php-simple-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I described above is quite similar to the one in this question: [Getting the text portion of a node using php Simple XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132231/getting-the-text-portion-of-a-node-using-php-simple-xml)

Short answer: SimpleXML can not handle text nodes, use a DOMDocument instance instead.  More details and solution in the referenced thread.