# simplexml_load_string has a bug?

Tags: php, xml

when i use simplexml_load_string, i find a question, lose data, after use it.

```
$xml = '<dblp>
<inproceedings key="conf/aaim/He07" mdate="2007-06-28">
<author>Dan He</author>
<title>
<i>BMA</i>
<sup>*</sup>
: An Efficient Algorithm for the One-to-Some Shortest Path Problem on Road Maps.
</title>
<pages>346-357</pages>
<year>2007</year>
<crossref>conf/aaim/2007</crossref>
<booktitle>AAIM</booktitle>
<ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-72870-2_33</ee>
<url>db/conf/aaim/aaim2007.html#He07</url>
</inproceedings>
</dblp>';
print_r(simplexml_load_string($xml));
```

running result:

```
  SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [inproceedings] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [key] => conf/aaim/He07
                    [mdate] => 2007-06-28
                )

            [author] => Dan He
            [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [i] => BMA
                    [sup] => *
                )

            [pages] => 346-357
            [year] => 2007
            [crossref] => conf/aaim/2007
            [booktitle] => AAIM
            [ee] => http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-72870-2_33
            [url] => db/conf/aaim/aaim2007.html#He07
        )

)
```

where is the data ': An Efficient Algorithm for the One-to-Some Shortest Path Problem on Road Maps.'? 
i hope xml to array.but data lost?thanks.
i want the result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [inproceedings] =>Array
    (
        [author] => Dan He
        [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMA
            [2] => *
            [5] => : An Efficient Algorithm for the One-to-Some Shortest Path Problem on Road Maps.
        )

        [pages] => 346-357
        [year] => 2007
        [crossref] => conf/aaim/2007
        [booktitle] => AAIM
        [ee] => http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-72870-2_33
        [url] => db/conf/aaim/aaim2007.html#He07
    )

)

)
```

Comment: I would expect it's in the SimpleXMLElement Object `title`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132231/getting-the-text-portion-of-a-node-using-php-simple-xml

Comment: Don't `print_r` SIMPLEXML classes, or at least don't arrive at any conclusion based on its output. They have some sort of representation for you that helps identify things a little, but a lot it is obscured underneath the surface.

Comment: Wording a question with "has a bug?" most often signals it's not a valid question for Stackoverflow, but a search request in the PHP bugtracker (there are exceptions to this rule, however this question does not fall into it). See as well https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Answer (score 3):

The first rule of SimpleXMLElement is: **you don't `print_r()` or `var_dump()` SimpleXMLElement Objects**

As for why you can't see the information, see this note from the [documentation](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children):

> **Note:** SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most methods. They cannot be viewed using var_dump() or anything else which can examine objects.

To access the title, you can do:

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$title = (string) $xmlObj->inproceedings->title;
```

The properties of a SimpleXMLElement objects are objects themselves, so you need to cast them as strings by adding `(string)` at the beginning (or by using [`strval()`](http://php.net/strval)). Now their values will be cast to a string instead of an object.

**What should you use when you want to inspect SimpleXML objects?**

You can use [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop)'s `simplexml_dump()` and `simplexml_tree()` helper functions. Here's the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug).

Comment: adding to Amal's answer, doing a `echo $xml->asXML();` is an option, probably `echo htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML());` if inside a HTML document.