# XML/PHP Complex Elements Parsing while preserving original markup

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am pretty new to coding and am still learning the ropes. I got an XML feed that I'm processing where, amongst other common data that is easy to process, I can get complex elements such as :

```
<para>Text before the <a href="www.alink.com">Link</a> more text after the link.</para>.
```

I get the data out of XML by simplexml_load_string($xml), perhapes this is where I'm going wrong. What is the best way to process an XML file where there may or may not be 'inline child' elements so that the output looks as it should. I can get the data out but what I end up with is two entries, "Text before the Link more text after the link." and the link itself.

This seems simple and I'm sure others may have run into this but I'm not sure how to preserve the original markup. I have been trying to find an answer to this with the good old google but I must be not using the right terms. Any help or pointers to a resource would be much appreciated. I have gone through a few tutorials online, but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SimpleXml can work on simple xmls ;)
Here may be solution for you [Use DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132231/getting-the-text-portion-of-a-node-using-php-simple-xml)

Comment: Hey Thanks @BojanT, definitely pointed me in the right direction. What I did was cast my simlexmlelement to a dom : 

    $string = dom_import_simplexml($simpleXmlElement)->textContent;  

This game a good output : Text before the Link, more text after the link. but it didn't preserve the <a href.../a>. Still a step closer or at least moving to a better direction. Maybe above will help someone. Hvala Bojane.