# &lt; and &gt; preventing text to be saved in array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, xml

What I am doing is obtaining the text within the `<To>` tags of an XML file (below) and saving it in an array on another php file. I am using this code:

```
  <?php
    $email = simplexml_load_file($path);
    foreach($email->thread as $thread){
            foreach($thread->email as $text){
                 $recipients[] = $text->To;
            }
    }
    print_r($recipients);
 ?>
```

What is visible on the browser is an array filled with addresses but for the array element of the below XML only a , (comma) is visible as the addresses within `&lt;` and `&gt;` codes are not being saved to array.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <thread>
      <name></name>
      <email>
         <EmailID></EmailID>
         <From></From>
         <To>&lt;agenda@ietf.org&gt; , &lt;discuss@apps.ietf.org&gt;</To>
         <Subject></Subject>
         <Text>
           <content> </content>           
         </Text>
      </email>
   </thread>
</root>
```

**MY CURRENT OUTPUT IN BROWSER:**

array ( [0] => simplexmlelement object ( [0] => discuss@apps.ietf.org ) [1] => simplexmlelement object ( [0] => discuss@apps.ietf.org,jpalme@dsv.su.se ) [2] => simplexmlelement object ( [0] => terry allen ) [3] => simplexmlelement object ( [0] => , ) ...etc

Comment: I'm going to imagine it's because it's thinking `<hello@whatever.com>` is a child node of `<To>`. Do you have access to whatever creates the XML? The values in the XML doc should really be wrapped in `<![CDATA[ ]]>` tags.

Comment: You speak of an XML file, but show code that deals with an `$email` data structure. Where is the connection?

Comment: @L.D please review my comment - could that be the issue?

Comment: This is clearly a wrong diagnostic. PHP arrays can hold everything, even binary strings. Coulld you please edit the question, remove all XML related stuff (which is red herring) and post a simple test case where you attempt to save a string into an array and it fails?

Comment: edited question to show format of xml file

Comment: If you decode `&lt;hello@whatever.com&gt;` you'll get `<hello@whatever.com>` are you viewing this in a browser?

Comment: What i am printing out to the browser is the text taken out from the XML tags. But when I have `&lt;hello@whatever.com&gt; ,  &lt;hello2@whatever.com&gt;` only the , is being shown.

Comment: Only what is shown? If you see `&lt;hello@whatever.com&gt;` in the browser you actually have a double encoded string. `&amp;lt;hello@whatever.com&amp;gt;` Why either of those cant be stored in an array is something I've never seen..

Comment: The comma. No the &lt; hello@whatever.com &gt; is not being shown on the browser.

Comment: You'll need to show an MVCE. https://eval.in/705542 I can't reproduce what you're describing..

Comment: Don't really know how to use this but I've tried to input the code I am using https://eval.in/705544. Does it show and can you understand it ?

Comment: Define `$email->thread` there.

Comment: understand that the XML file contains a list of threads, and each thread contains a list of different emails. the foreach loops are being used that foreach thread and foreach email in these threads obtain the text within <To> tags

Comment: If you can't show us a reproducible example of the issue we cant help you. I've already shown that string can be stored in an array.

Comment: I've updated the question again, hopefully like this you can envision how my code is and what is happening.

Comment: I'm going to go back to my comment +1 hour ago... You are viewing this in a browser. I've also created an MVCE demonstrating this https://eval.in/705575.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is treating `<hello@whatever.com>` as a child node of `<To>` - so there's no value to actually save.

You have a couple of options, the ideal method is to edit the XML so that the node values are wrapped in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tags. This will ensure the value in the node is treated as a value and not a child node.

Alternatively, an uglier solution would be to [find the children of the `<To>` node using children()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and then make use of the [getName()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php) method. This will return the node name. It would work, but it's ugly.

Edit: Alternatively, you can reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5132764/297243) - it explains how to use `DOM` and then force the read of the contents of `<To>` as text.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot just edit the XML file since the code is going to be tested with the original XML. Using the second solution, would this cause a problem to proper text without any <>'s ? Meaning would <To>Maria</To> still be saved properly?

Comment: You'd need to incorporate a bit of logic that checks to see if <To> is _empty_ - as in it has no direct value. If so, you can look if it has any children. The orignal XML is incorrect and poorly formatted - so I'd really focus on that if you can.

Comment: I also have an example where to the XML contains <To> &lt;hello&whatever.com&gt; , &lt;hello2@whatever.com&gt; </To> . In this case the , is being saved within the array so I don't know about php treating it a child node.

Comment: Could be the comma is causing it to be read a string, and not as an XML node?

Comment: Isn't the text within the tags supposed to be read as a string? When I have <To> Maria </To> isn't Maria being read as a string?

Comment: PHP will auto typecast the contents of <To> depending on what it thinks is in there. I've updated my answer with a link to another answer that explains how to force the read of the contents of the node as text.

Answer (score 1):

I spot two problems here:

1. The SimpleXML extension does not create regular objects. It creates dynamically generated objects that are expanded as you read them. For that reason, you can't normally use `print_r()` to inspect XML contents reliably.
2. Similarly, class properties that represent XML stuff are dynamically generated **objects**, not strings. They only look strings because they have an internal `__toString()` method that extracts textual data when you cast them to string. This works when you `echo` them but not when, for instance, you append them to an array (because that won't trigger a cast operation).

(Needless to say, if you print XML to a browser you need to ensure it doesn't get rendered as HTML, either by sending an appropriate `Content-Type` header or by inspecting raw source in the browser, typically by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.)

I suggest you force string casting yourself:

```
foreach($email->thread as $thread){
    foreach($thread->email as $text){
        $recipients[] = (string)$text->To;
    }
}
print_r($recipients);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of SimpleXML_load_string() function which will XML to an object. Then convert the object to JSON using json_encode($obj) and decode it to get the array (json_decode()).

Comment: this answer also can be given as comment.